# React how to store properties list in a variable and pass them to element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find anything on StackOverflow nor Google.

I wanted to know how to store several props in a single variable, and then pass them to the element, if that's even possible.

For example, let's say I have the following props:

`classname="..." width="100" height="50`

How do I do something like this:

`var props= {classname="..." width="100" height="50"}`

And then this:

`<MyComponent props>`

Comment: You can use [spread syntax](https://kevinyckim33.medium.com/jsx-spread-operator-component-props-meaning-3c9bcadd2493): `<MyComponent {...props} />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object:

```
let props= {classname : "..." width : "100" height : "50"}
```

and just [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it :

```
<MyComponent {...props}>
```

MyComponent gets properties like `width`, `height` and `className`

Answer (score 0):

To declare the props

```js
const props = {
  div: {
    className: "my_class",
    id: "my-id",
    style: {
      textAlign: "center"
    }
  }
}
```

to add props to an element

```html
<div {...props.div} />
```